# WP_query() Simulate Missing "NOT" relation to Reverse Results?

Tags: wp-query

I have a working and **complex** "args" ("tax_query") array which returns results.

I now wish to get the missing results, this is a **"boolean" NOT** operation (which "relation" doesn't support).  Can this be done (without rewriting the whole query or doing multiple queries)?  I realise that minor tweaking of the args will be required (for post type).

This is an example:

```
array (
  'post_type' => 'plant',
  'orderby' => 'title',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'tax_query' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'relation' => 'OR',
        0 => 
        array (
          'taxonomy' => 'plant_category',
          'field' => 'name',
          'terms' => 'Popular (home)',
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          'taxonomy' => 'plant_category',
          'field' => 'name',
          'terms' => 'Popular (bulk)',
        ),
        2 => 
        array (
          'taxonomy' => 'plant_category',
          'field' => 'name',
          'terms' => 'Cottage',
        ),
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'relation' => 'OR',
        0 => 
        array (
          'taxonomy' => 'light_conditions',
          'field' => 'name',
          'terms' => 'Full Sun',
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          'taxonomy' => 'light_conditions',
          'field' => 'name',
          'terms' => 'Partial Shade',
        ),
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'relation' => 'OR',
        0 => 
        array (
          'taxonomy' => 'soil_conditions',
          'field' => 'name',
          'terms' => 'Moist',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

In Words: (Popular (home) OR Popular (bulk) OR Cottage) AND (Full Sun OR Partial Shade) AND Moist

Comment: What are the args?

Comment: @JacobPeattie  I have added an example to the OP.  I now want to see all the items that the "tax_query" didn't return (without rewriting the whole query).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use `NOT IN` for the `operator` to achieve this along with switching some of the `relation`s from `OR`s to `AND`s.

```
array (
  'taxonomy' => 'plant_category',
  'field' => 'name',
  'terms' => 'Popular (home)',
  'operator' => 'NOT IN',
),
```